# Android app black skin

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-interface, usability

White and other bright colours on AMOLED screens burn it in and decrease battery life.

How about a completely black skin?

Comment: A night mode would do really well

Comment: I'd say a 'dark' skin, not a black one..

Comment: I meant a skin with completely black backgrounds